# Dagger2 how to use constructor injection

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, android-mvp

I've read more about Dagger2 and I find that is similar to `Butterknife`, because when I need to use it I create a module, and use:

```
   ((MyApp) getApplication()).createAppComponent().inject(this);
```

to use, for example, this:

```
@Inject
RegisterPresenter presenter;
```

but I don't understand how to use constructor injection. I've a case(use model-view-presenter):

```
private Register.View view;
private RegisterModel model;
private StorageModel storageModel;
private DatabaseModel databaseModel;
private Uri compressPath;

List<String > stringList;
String uid;

@Inject
public RegisterPresenter() {
    model = new RegisterModel(this);
    storageModel = new StorageModel(this);
    databaseModel = new DatabaseModel(this);

}
```

is it correct? Or I need to do it?

```
 @Inject
    public RegisterPresenter(RegisterModel model, StorageModel storageModel, DatabaseModel databaseModel) {
        this.model = model;
        this.storageModel = storageModel;
        this.databaseModel = databaseModel;
    }
```

because if I use the second code, in my activity(View) I need to do it:

```
protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        presenter.setView(this);
    }
```

so how could construct the Presenter? Or if I need to create this in Activity, is it correct to pass the module from the view?

**EDIT:** these are my models:

```
public class FirebaseModel implements Model, FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener {


    FirebaseAuth auth;

    Presenter presenter;
    FirebaseUser user;

    @Inject
    public FirebaseModel(Presenter presenter) {
        this.presenter = presenter;
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    }


    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        user = auth.getCurrentUser();
        presenter.updateUser(user);

    }


    @Override
    public void loadUser() {

        auth.addAuthStateListener(this);
    }
}
public class StorageModel implements Register.Storage,OnCompleteListener <UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>{

Register.Presenter presenter;
StorageReference storage;

@Inject
public StorageModel(Register.Presenter presenter) {
    this.presenter = presenter;
    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("gs://firebase-happypark.appspot.com");
}



@Override
public void onTryToUpdateUser(Uri path,String uid) {
    if(path != null) {
        StorageReference riversRef = storage.child("uid").child("ImgProfile/" + path.getLastPathSegment());
        UploadTask uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(path);
        Log.d("ssd", "sto qua");
        uploadTask.addOnCompleteListener(this);
     }
 }


//UNNECESSARY

@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        presenter.onUploadCompleted();
    } else {
        presenter.onUploadError(task.getException());
    }
}
```

}

Thank you

Comment: second example is correct

Comment: @tompadre how to inject a field of RegisterPresenter with this strucure?

Comment: Maybe have a look at the answer from the other week
http://stackoverflow.com/a/43822373/1837367

Comment: @DavidMedenjak I don't understand how to use the Inject if constructor has parameters

Answer (score 0):

Presenter would be something like this:

```
public class RegisterPresenter implements RegisterContract.Presenter {

private Register.View view;
private RegisterModel model;
private StorageModel storageModel;
private DatabaseModel databaseModel;
private Uri compressPath;

List<String > stringList;
String uid;

@Inject
 public RegisterPresenter(Register.View view, RegisterModel model, StorageModel storageModel, DatabaseModel databaseModel) {

    this.view = view;
    this.model = model;
    this.storageModel = storageModel;
    this.databaseModel = databaseModel;
}

@Override
public void someMethodFromContract(){}

//or anything else you have in mind

}
```

And then call it in onResume like this

```
presenter.someMethodFromContract();
```

Comment: but how Dagger instantiate model, storageModel and databaseModel if I call someMethodFromContract() ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "instantiate model"? If you have those storage and database models already done correct, just make some interface with dependency from that models and make inject method in that interface. If you mean how exactly inject into your class then i think your first code line in the question should do the work.